# How to loop through a row in each column even the data is NULL or empty string?

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, sql-server-2016

I have a VB.NET program which runs as a Windows Service. All it does is connect to a table in SQL Server 2016 and reads data (if any exist) and does some transaction posting to an ERP System. Now in that table (`ALL_LABOR_DETAILS`) I have 29 columns and some of them could be 'NULL' or empty string value per given row. You can see I've used `IsDBNull` function for those columns only in my code.

Following is my code which I'm moving through the rows and columns in the dataset but I've noticed whenever it comes to a row with a 'NULL' value for `operationComplete` or `strDefaultBin` or `strLotNo` column it does not read is as a `Empty String`, instead it tries to move to another row with no NULL record and read that row instead.

Also it throws me this error in my log file whenever it encounters a NULL value in

> operationComplete
> Error: Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid.

Code:

```
    Dim postCount3 As SqlDataReader

    Dim newServer3 As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("newServer")

    Try
        Using cn3 As New SqlConnection(newServer3),
            cmd3 As New SqlCommand(Sql3, cn3)
            cn3.Open()
            postCount3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader()

            If postCount3.HasRows Then

                While postCount3.Read()

                    Try
                        SourceID = Trim(postCount3.Item(0))
                        strSourceName = Trim(postCount3.Item(1))
                        strOrderNumber = Trim(postCount3.Item(4))
                        strItemNumber = Trim(postCount3.Item(11))
                        strOperationNumber = Trim(postCount3.Item(7))
                        strCurrentStatus = Trim(postCount3.Item(2))
                        strDepartment = Trim(postCount3.Item(5))
                        strWorkCenter = Trim(postCount3.Item(6))
                        strOperator = Trim(postCount3.Item(8))
                        strTrxDate = Trim(postCount3.Item(3))
                        strPosted = Trim(postCount3.Item(14))
                        totalLaborHrs = Trim(postCount3.Item(9))
                        laborFeetProduced = Trim(postCount3.Item(10))

                        If Not IsDBNull(Trim(postCount3.Item(22))) Then
                            operationComplete = Trim(postCount3.Item(22))
                        Else
                            operationComplete = Trim(postCount3.Item(22)).ToString()
                        End If

                        If Not IsDBNull(Trim(postCount3.Item(13))) Then
                            strDefaultBin = Trim(postCount3.Item(13))
                        Else
                            strDefaultBin = Trim(postCount3.Item(13)).ToString()
                        End If

                        If Not IsDBNull(Trim(postCount3.Item(12))) Then
                            strLotNo = Trim(postCount3.Item(12))
                        Else
                            strLotNo = Trim(postCount3.Item(12)).ToString()
                        End If

                        FileIO.WriteLog("")
                        'Print Source  ID
                        FileIO.WriteLog(SourceID)
                        'Print Source Name
                        FileIO.WriteLog(strOrderNumber & " Source Name = " & strSourceName)
                        'Print Order Number
                        FileIO.WriteLog(strOrderNumber & " Order Number = " & strOrderNumber)
                        'Print Item Number
                        FileIO.WriteLog(strOrderNumber & " Item Number = " & strItemNumber)
                        'Print Operation Number
                        FileIO.WriteLog(strOrderNumber & " Operation Number = " & strOperationNumber)
                        'Print Department
                        FileIO.WriteLog(strOrderNumber & " Department = " & strDepartment)
                        'Print Work Center
                        FileIO.WriteLog(strOrderNumber & " Work Center = " & strWorkCenter)
                        'Print Operator
                        FileIO.WriteLog(strOrderNumber & " Operator = " & strOperator)
                        'Print Current Status
                        FileIO.WriteLog(strOrderNumber & " Current Status = " & strCurrentStatus)
                        'Print Total Labor Hours
                        FileIO.WriteLog(strOrderNumber & " Total Labor Hours = " & totalLaborHrs)
                        'Print Labor Feet Produced
                        FileIO.WriteLog(strOrderNumber & " Labor Feet Produced = " & laborFeetProduced)
                        'Print Operation Complete
                        FileIO.WriteLog(strOrderNumber & " Operation Complete = " & operationComplete)
                        'Print Default Bin
                        FileIO.WriteLog(strOrderNumber & " Default Bin = " & strDefaultBin)
                        'Print Lot No
                        FileIO.WriteLog(strOrderNumber & " Lot No = " & strLotNo)

                    Catch ex As Exception
                        FileIO.WriteLog("Error : " & ex.Message)
                    End Try

                   Continue While
                   End While
              postCount3.Close()
            cn3.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        FileIO.WriteLog(strOrderNumber & " There was an error getting the laborDetails FROM ALL_LABOR_DETAILS table WHERE posted = '' AND work_order IS NOT NULL ORDER BY SOURCE_ID. Error Message : " & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: That code in your first line looks like a SQL Injection concern.

Comment: @Larnu thank you, just removed. Did not notice it.

Comment: Removing it from the question doesn't fix the problem; you need to fix your code and **parameterise**.

Comment: @Larnu could you please explain what you're trying to mean? Am I not supposed to have SQL queries in my program or should I have it in some environment variable file? Like the way I have it currently is, specify the query in the program and import the database and all credentials from my app.config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to Trim DBNull.  Try changing this(the Else)

```
operationComplete = Trim(postCount3.Item(22)).ToString()
```

to

```
operationComplete = postCount3.Item(22).ToString()
```

Same for the others.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot implicitly cast dbnull to a string which is what youa redoing with the trim command. It accepts a string parameter and vb tries to cast. If null is an option, I would recommend tryParse.
Y organization uses a wrapper class to parse the value of return a nothing for these sorts of calls. The class structure is simple enough and looks something like the below though with a string we return string.empty.

```vb
    Public Module Parsers
        Function ParseString(value as object) as String
            Dim result as string
            If String.TryParse(value, result) then
                Return result
            End if
            Return string.empty
        End function
    End module
```

And then call it like

```
    strSourceName = Trim(Parsers.ParseString(postCount3.Item(1)))
```